# Google sheets: Create function that calculates depending on dropdown menu text

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create google sheet that calculates value depending on drop down text menu field selection.

I have a drop down menu with bunch of options:

- Untrained
- Improvisation
- Trained
- Expert
- Master
- Legendary

And when I select one of given options, it would calculate different value dependent on the text selected.

First I tried IF option but it only allows up to 3 variables. Next up I tried ARRAYFORMULA but I couldn't figure it out on how to use it correctly.

EDIT: Picture below of the table with bit more explanation which would hopefully clarify the problem.

- So when I select Master from the drop down menu, it would automatically calculate value in selected cell C18.
- In this case it would be 31 *=SUM($D$12+F18+G18+$C$7+6)*

If I can get just starting point on how to create one of those, I can then expand it on others on my own. Any help would be appreciated on how to implement this.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Tedinoz answer was really good and very close to what I was after. Unfortunately it appears to be way too complex and just far enough from my intent for me to really understand enough to finetune and edit it to fill my goal.

I changed the sheet for editable for anyone with link, if it helps:
*https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x2koOHFTSrc1BOvm0tXQ5NFV0_Z8ygohTP9zrLjew1A/edit?usp=sharing*

Now what is the problem in suggested solution:

- It appears to always use dexterity modifier instead of specified modifier and I don't understand solution given enough to correct it myself.
- All the saves displays just 0 and I don't know why.

  - How difficult would it be to expand same for all cells next to drop down fields?
  - Ideally it would be easy to use character sheet where one just fills few basic stuff and then the sheet would calculate rest.

Comment: When you use the dropdown option, it will update the cell's contents. This allows you to reference the value in a lookup (ie `=A1` would give the selected dropdown value). Now you have a few different options, such as using a LOOKUP function, which would allow you to have a lookup table for associated values, you could chain multiple IF statements, or however you really want to handle it.

Comment: `I am trying to create excel sheet` The title and tags reference "Google Sheets". Would you please clarify and/or correct the opening sentence.

Comment: `It appears to always use dexterity modifier instead of specified modifier`, `All the saves displays just 0` - error in the formula; refer adjusted answer

Comment: `appears to be way too complex`. The formula contains three calculations: 1) Proficiency, 2) Attributes, 3) extras. Once you can distinguish between these, then adapting the formula to your own spreadsheet becomes much more logical (and doable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Skills - Cell D18**
`=arrayformula(iferror(($C$7*(vlookup(D18:D37,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,3,0)))+(vlookup(D18:D37,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,2,0)),)+IFERROR(vlookup(vlookup(E18:E37,Sheet2!$E$2:$F$7,2,0),$B$11:$D$16,3,0),)+(F18:F37+G18:G37))`

**Saves - Cell J16**
`=arrayformula(iferror(($C$7*(vlookup(K16:K18,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,3,0)))+(vlookup(K16:K18,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,2,0)),)+IFERROR(vlookup(vlookup(L16:L18,Sheet2!$E$2:$F$7,2,0),$B$11:$D$16,3,0),)+(M16:M18))`

---

The formula has several parts:

- **`ARRAYFORMULA`** - create values for all the rows within a section
- **`IFERROR`** - to ensure that a blank in a "Proficiency" or a "stat" cell does not generate #N/A result
- **`CALCULATION`**

  - Sum of the following:
  - **Proficiency**:

    - **Level**: `$C$7` by
    - **Level Multiplier**: `vlookup(D18:D37,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,3,0)` . This ensures that `Untrained` and `Improvision` score zero for the Level. The multiplier for the other levels = "1", so they score the value of the level for that sheet.
  - **Attribute modifier**: `vlookup(vlookup(E18:E37,Sheet2!$E$2:$F$7,2,0),$B$11:$D$16,3,0)` - a nested VLOOKUP searches the `Stat` value in a range on Sheet2 and returns the full "Attribute" name; then searches the "Attribute" name in the current sheet and returns the "mod" value.
  - **Miscellaneous**: `+(+F18:F37+G18:G37)` adds any relevant miscellaneous values.

---

**Sheet1**

[image: SHEETMARK3]

**Validation**

[image: validation]

**Assumptions - Sheet2**

[image: ASSUMPTIONSMARK3]

---

**Updated 28 Aug 2023** : This answer has been updated:

- to correct an earlier solution that used a fixed value for `Level` instead of the specific value of `Level` on each sheet.
- to correct the formula to return the Attribute score.

Comment: Note the update.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, it ended up being lot more complicated than I was expecting.